# Deleting a list of azure blobs blocks express/nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-storage, async.js

Given a list of blobs I want to delete them one by one (since there's no batch/bulk delete of blobs in azure storage sdk) without blocking node's event loop or the express server. The deletion is triggered by (and runs on) a request. But although the entire flow is made as async as possible, the express server becomes unresponsive once the deletion starts, sometimes some endpoints returning 500.

```
const async       = require('async');
const azure       = require('azure-storage');
const Promise     = require('bluebird');

const blobService = azure.createBlobService(CONFIG.CONNECTION_STRING);

// Endpoint
app.delete(`${BASE_URL}/files/:date`, deleteFiles);

const deleteFiles = async (req, res) => {

  const date = req.params.date;

  if (!date) {

    return res.status(400).send();

  }

  await deleteBlobs(date).catch((err) => {

    return res.status(500).send(err);

  });

  res.status(200).send();

};

const deleteBlobs = (date) => {

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    // findFiles calls blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix and performs some async.map on the returned entrieds
    const blobNames = await findFiles(date)
      .catch(err => log.error('findFiles failed in deleteBlobs.', err));

    async.each(
      blobNames,
      (blobName, callback) => {

        blobService.deleteBlob(CONTAINER, blobName, (deleteError) => {

          if (deleteError) {

            return callback(deleteError);

          }

          callback();

        });

      },
      err => {

        if (err)  {

          return reject(err);

        }

        resolve();

      });

  });

};
```

So what am I missing? Why the server becomes unresponsive till the deletion finishes?

Mentions (maybe it helps): The express server/app is hosted in Azure on a Basic (B1) service plan.

Comment: I think the problem is not specific to your app and most likely related to the browser cache. Check [@Josh Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624268/how-to-make-node-js-handle-multiple-requests-efficiently) and see if it helps.

Comment: Browser cache has nothing to do with that because all the requests are getting blocked, not only the same one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are 1 possible reason which could lead your express unresponsive.

Too many delete async operations, which creates lots of callback I/O events at a short time. Node.js may serve these event at first, and stuck the Node.js to deal with other incoming HTTP requests.

Can you use async.eachLimit instead of async.each to set a lower concurrency limitation?

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit

Comment: This is amazing. The server still feels like hanging when using eachLimit with a limit of 10, but definitely the problem was the one you mentioned because i see a huge improvement. Deleting 1000 blobs, it was taking 15 seconds, now it dropped to only 5. Thanks a lot! Will continue playing with the limit till i find a good balance.